# Differentiability of largest eigenvalue for a $C^1$ function

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, perturbation-theory, matrix-analysis

I encountered following interesting statement:

If $f: [a, b] \to M_n(\mathbb C)$ is a $C^1$ ( $C^1$ in the interior and left/right differentiable over the end points) function over an interval $[a, b]$ where the image $f(t)$ is Hermitian everywhere. Then there exists an almost everywhere differentiable function $\lambda(t)$ which is the largest eigenvalue of $f(t)$ for every $t \in (a, b)$ such that the following equality holds almost everywhere
\begin{align*}
\frac {d\lambda(t)}{dt} = v(t)^* \left(\frac{d}{dt} f \right) v(t),
\end{align*}
where $v(t)$ is the unit vector such that for every $t$, $\lambda(t) = v(t)^* f(t) v(t)$. No regularity conditions are assumed for $v$.

How to prove the statement?

EDIT 1: 
After some thoughts: we know the ordered eigenvalues of Hermitian matrices are Lipschtiz with rank $1$. Note $f$ is Lipschtiz since $f$ is $C^1$ over a compact interval. Denote the rank to be $c$. So for $s, t \in [a, b]$, 
$$|\lambda( s) - \lambda(t)| = |\lambda_{\max}(f(s)) - \lambda_{\max}(f(t)) |  \le \|f(s) - f(t)\| \le c |s -t|.$$
$\lambda(t)$ is indeed Lipschtiz and thus differentiable almost everywhere on $[a, b]$. But I still don't know how to reach the formula.

---

EDIT 2: I found a source for the proof which is posted as an alternative answer. But I have a minor question over the proof. If someone knows the answer, please post a comment under the proof posted by me.

Comment: I don't think it's quite correct as it stands . . . you might consider the case when the "largest eigenvalue" has multiplicity greater than $1$ . . . Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis: I think I missed the condition that the image is Hermitian everywhere. How does it look now? Thanks.

Comment: It's much easier this new way of course, but I'm still concerned about the multiplicity issue.

Comment: @RobertLewis: The statement is on differentiability 'almost everywhere'. I would imagine the multiplicity should not matter too much.

Comment: Maybe the theorem of Courant-Fischer will help here, because we have an explicit formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formally, if $fv=\lambda v$ and $v^*fv=\lambda$, where $||v||=1$, then

$v'^*v=0$ and $2v'^*fv+v^*f'v=\lambda'$, that is $\lambda'=v^*f'v$.

When $f$ is analytic, we can find an analytic parametrization of its eigenvalues and eigenvectors. Yet, the eigenvalues may cross, and, consequently, the largest eigenvalue, as the maximum of smooth functions, is only Lipschitz. Thus, even playing on $f$, we cannot do better than Lipschitz for $\lambda_{\max}$.

On the other hand, the above formula may stand in $t_0$, only if $\lambda'(t_0)$ exists and $v(t_0)$ is unique.

EDIT 2.  In general, when $\lambda$ is multiple in $t_0$, $\lambda$ is not differentiable in $t_0$ (cf. example below); of course, it may be otherwise: for example, choose $A(t)=I_n$. In the sequel, we consider only the $t_0$ s.t. $\lambda(t_0)$ is a simple eigenvalue of $A(t_0)$ (cf. example below). Moreover $v'(t_0)$ must exist.

$\textbf{Lemma}$.  $M=\{t;\lambda(t)$ is a multiple eigenvalue$\}$ is a closed real subset.

$\textbf{Proof}$. $\lambda(t)\in M$ iff $\chi_{A(t)}(\lambda(t))=\dfrac{\partial{\chi_{A(t)}}}{\partial {x}}(\lambda(t))=0$ where $\chi_{A(t)}(x)$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A(t)$. The conclusion comes from the fact that the functions $t\rightarrow \chi_{A(t)}(\lambda(t)),t\rightarrow \dfrac{\partial{\chi_{A(t)}}}{\partial {x}}(\lambda(t))$ are continuous.  $\square$

When $\lambda(t_0)$ is a simple eigenvalue, $\lambda(t)$ is a simple eigenvalue in a neighborhood $U$ of $t_0$; then $\lambda,v$ are $C^1$ functions on $U$ and the above formula is correct in $U$.

Morover, if we want that $\lambda$ is a.e. differentiable (with the above formula), then it suffices to assume that, a.e. $t$, $\lambda(t)$ is a simple eigenvalue of $A(t)$, that is, $M$ has measure $0$.

Example. Let $f(t)=diag(2t,t^3+1)$. Then $\lambda(t)=t^3+1$ when $t\geq 1$, $\lambda(t)=2t$ when $t\in (1-\epsilon,1)$. Then $\lambda'_+(1)=3,\lambda'_-(1)=2$ and the derivative does not exist in $t=1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you explain how you conclude $\lambda'=v^*f'v$ from $v'^*v=0$ and $2v'^*fv+v^*f'v=\lambda'$?

Comment: Because $v'^*fv=\lambda v'^*v=0$.

Comment: To do the operation $v'*v$ (differentiating an eigenvector), we need to assume analyticity of $f$, right?

Comment: No, you differentiate wrt. the real $t$: $(a(t)+ib(t))'=a'(t)+ib'(t)$ is valid for $a,b\in C^1$. However, the function $v\rightarrow v^*$ is not differentiable wrt. the complex vector $v$ (that is as a function defined over $\mathbb{C}^n$).

Comment: Thanks. I have two more question: (1) How do we know there is a $C^1$ choice of $v(t)$? (2) I could not see why $M=\{t: \lambda(t) \text{ is a multiple eigenvalue} \}$ is closed. Sorry to have too many questions.

Comment: For point(1). A known result (I have no reference on hand) says that if $f\in C^p$, then there is a $C^p$ local parametrization of any couple $(\lambda,v)$ s.t. $\lambda$ is a simple eigenvalue (use the implicit function theorem). For point 2. I'll give an answer tomorrow;

Comment: Hello loup. Thinking about your last comment: how could the part be true: if $f \in C^p$, then there is local parametrization of $(\lambda, v)$ such that $\lambda$ is simple? Are you assuming $\lambda$ is simple as a priori? If not, how can this happen? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's the dark side of the Force! If $f\in C^p,p\leq\infty$, then there are $C^p$ parameterization of $(\lambda,v$, only for the simple eigenvalues  $\lambda$. If we drop this last hypothesis, then $v$ may not have even a continuous parameterization when $f\in C^{\infty}$; however, if $f$ is an analytic function of ONE real (and not several) value, then there are  parameterizations of all $\lambda,v$ without any hypothesis about simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

Here I found a proof in [Matrix Riccati Equations in Control and Systems Theory](https://books.google.com/books/about/Matrix_Riccati_Equations_in_Control_and.html?id=DmyfOTn_D9kC&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button#v=onepage&q&f=false). It is on Page $164$. Unfortunately Google does not allow to preview that page. I took almost verbatim from the proof.

For each $t$, let $\lambda(t)$ be the maximal eigenvalue and $x(t)$ be the unit vector corresponding to the maximal eigenvalue. Let us introduce a function
\begin{align*}
  \Lambda(s, t) = x^*(t) f(s) x(t).
\end{align*}
For each fixed $t$, the function $s \mapsto x^*(t) f(s) x(t)$ is $C^1$ and $\lambda(t) = \Lambda(t, t)$. Since the maximal eigenvalue is defined by
\begin{align*}
  \lambda(s) = \max_{\|x\|=1} x^* f(s) x,
\end{align*}
we infer that $\Lambda(s, t) \le \lambda(s) = \Lambda(s,s)$ for all $s,t$. Then we conclude for all $t', t'' \in [a,b]$ with $t' < t''$:
\begin{align*}
\Lambda(t'', t'') - \Lambda(t', t'') &= \lambda(t'') - \Lambda(t', t'') \\
&\ge \lambda(t'') - \lambda(t') \\
&\ge \Lambda(t'', t') - \Lambda(t', t'),
\end{align*}
yielding
\begin{align}
\tag{$\star$}
\label{eq:1}
\int_{t'}^{t''} \frac{\partial \Lambda}{\partial s} (\sigma, t'') d \sigma \ge \lambda(t'') - \lambda(t') \ge \int_{t'}^{t''} \frac{\partial \Lambda}{\partial s} (\sigma, t') d \sigma.
\end{align}
Since $\frac{\partial \Lambda}{\partial s} (\sigma, t)$ is continuous in first arguemnt, then on $[a,b]$, it is bounded and we conclude $\lambda(t)$ is Lipschitz. Consequently, it is differentiable almost everywhere.

At any point $t_0$ of differentiability of $\lambda(t)$, choose $h>0$ and estimate the difference
\begin{align*}
\lambda(t_0+h)-\lambda(t_0) - x^*(t_0) \frac{df}{dt} (t_0) x(t_0) h = \lambda(t_0+h) -\lambda(t_0) - \frac{\partial \Lambda}{\partial s} (t_0, t_0)h.
\end{align*}
Utilizing the lower estimate in \eqref{eq:1} by choosing $t'=t_0$ and $t'' =t_0+h$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
\lambda(t_0+h) -\lambda(t_0) - \frac{\partial \Lambda}{\partial s} (t_0, t_0)h \ge \int_{t_0}^{t_0+h} \frac{\partial \Lambda}{\partial s} (\sigma, t_0) d \sigma.
\end{align*}
Since $\sigma \to \frac{\partial \Lambda}{\partial s}(\sigma, t_0)$ is continuous, as $h \to 0+$, then the latter integral is $o(h)$ and we conclude
\begin{align*}
\frac{d\lambda}{dt}(t_0) \ge \frac{\partial \Lambda}{\partial s}(t_0, t_0).
\end{align*}
Similarly by taking $t' = t_0 -h$ and $t''=t_0$ and utilizing the upper estimate in \eqref{eq:1}, we get
\begin{align*}
\frac{d\lambda}{dt}(t_0) \le \frac{\partial \Lambda}{\partial s}(t_0, t_0).
\end{align*}

---

There is on minor part I hope someone could comment: in arriving the formula for derivative of $\lambda(t)$, it says **at the point of differentiability $t_0$**, but it seems to me the estimates are global. Of course we know $\lambda(t)$ could not be globally differentiable on $[a,b]$. My question is: why isn’t  the derivation not applicable for those points not differentiable?